# Very new to Jquery. Trying to create a Photoset grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to Jquery, and I am trying to figure out to create a Photo set grid that when you click the pictures get bigger using a jquery plugin that I found online. My code looks like this.

```
    <script>

        $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').photosetGrid({
            highresLinks: true,
            rel: 'withhearts-gallery',
            gutter: '2px',

            onComplete: function() {
                $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').attr('style', '');
                $('.photoset-grid-lightbox a').colorbox({
                    photo: true,
                    scalePhotos: true,
                    maxHeight:'90%',
                    maxWidth:'90%'
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="photoset-grid-lightbox" data-layout="131" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="images/InspirationalQuote.jpg" />
        <img src="images/jakachu-tiger.jpg"  />
        <img src="images/Japanese_Painting_by_trinifellah.jpg" />
    </div>
```

The link to the plugin:

http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/

Any help would be gladly accepted. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DamianG/6UjsB/

Comment: Can you tell us if you're seeing any errors in the console? You can also try simulating your work through http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: try wrapping your JS code with $(function() { your code here });

Comment: @roobeedeedada There doesn't appear to be any errors in my Dreamweaver application. Here is the jsfiddle though. http://jsfiddle.net/DamianG/6UjsB/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this is the end result you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/6UjsB/1/), you need to make sure:

1. Your jQuery library is included in the  of your document
2. Your photoset-grid JS is included in the  of your document, after
   jQuery

Then, include the following, wrapped in jQuery's document.ready check, as [@pl4g4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652917/pl4g4) suggested, included afterwards:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').photosetGrid({
            highresLinks: true,
            rel: 'withhearts-gallery',
            gutter: '2px',

            onComplete: function () {
                $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').attr('style', '');
                $('.photoset-grid-lightbox a').colorbox({
                    photo: true,
                    scalePhotos: true,
                    maxHeight: '90%',
                    maxWidth: '90%'
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm guessing the photoset-grid didn't load? This would be because the contents of your  element get loaded first, then whatever's in the body. By wrapping your code with

```
$(document).ready( function() { /* your code here */ });
```

or the shorthand

```
$(function(){ /* your code here */ });
```

You ensure the browser reads your javascript, but defers running your $.photosetGrid() block of code until after the HTML of the page has been rendered. Otherwise, jQuery can't see the Document Object Model, so $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').length will return 0 - there's no such element on the page, [as demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/6UjsB/2/).

A bit more info on [jQuery(document).ready();](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)